# Outputting data to an NSString from a plist

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nsstring

I'm extracting some string data from a plist:

```
<dict>
<key>Feb 7, 2000</key>
<array>
    <string>7</string>
    <string>8</string>
</array>
<key>Jan 27, 2001</key>
<array>
    <string>8</string>
    <string>7</string>
</array>
```

and using the following code to output the data in a UILabel:

```
  NSString * myString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",self.data];

    myLabel.text = myString;
```

the output is being displayed as `( 7, 8)`

does anyone know how i might go about removing the parenthesis and comma. and also separating the values so I could display something like `first: 7 second: 8`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Example:

```
<dict>
<key>Feb 7, 2000</key>
<array>
    <string>7</string>
    <string>8</string>
</array>
<key>Jan 27, 2001</key>
<array>
    <string>8</string>
    <string>7</string>
</array>
</dict>
```

Code:

```
NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path]; 

for(id key in dict) {
    NSLog(@"First:%@ Second:%@", [[dict objectForKey:key] objectAtIndex:0],  [[dict objectForKey:key] objectAtIndex:1]);
}
```

Output:

```
First:7 Second:8
First:8 Second:7
```

**EDIT** *(response to comment)*

First you need to determine the keys within the `NSMutableDictionary`.
Load the `.plist` file, loop through and add the keys to an `NSMutableArray`.

```
NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path]; 
NSMutableArray *keys = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for(id key in dict) [keys addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",key]];
```

Make sure the array can be accessed by the `UIPickerView`.
The `UIPickerView` should be able to retrieve the keys like this:

```
- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component;
{
    return [keys objectAtIndex:row];
}

- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component;
{
    return [keys count];
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView;
{
    return 1;
}
```

Finally, update the `UILabel` like this:

```
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    theLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"First:%@ Second:%@", 
                      [[dict objectForKey:[keys objectAtIndex:row]] objectAtIndex:0],  
                      [[dict objectForKey:[keys objectAtIndex:row]] objectAtIndex:1]];
}
```

The `UIPickerView` now contains the following rows:

```
Feb 7, 2000
Jan 27, 2001
```

When for example "Jan 27, 2001" is selected, the `UILabel` shows:

```
First:8 Second:7
```

Comment: quick question. that outputs every single string value. how would i go about outputting just the string values for just one particular key. the key in this case would be one selected in a UIPicker. thanks again.